# MS Excel Formula For Fitting Things in Buckets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet that defines a collection/container of shelves, and then an assortment of objects that can be placed on the shelves

So, there are 4 collections of shelves defined in a table, each with Shelf 1, Shelf 2, Shelf 3 having a set length.  But for each collection, the length of the shelves may vary.  So collection A has a  Shelf 1 = 12", Shelf 2 = 12", Shelf 3 = 0".  Collection C might be Shelf 1 = 20", Shelf 2 = 20", Shelf 3 = 20".

For the objects, they are defined in a table with a given space requirement.  This space requirement may be linked to a specific shelve, or it may be allowed for "any".  So, Object X requires 3" on Shelf 1, plus 6" on any Shelf.  Object Y requires 10" on Shelf 1, and 6" on Shelf 2 or Shelf 3.

There is a dropdown where the user selects the container they want to use.  There is a separate table that lists all of the available objects, and allows the user to enter a quantity for each.  What I am trying to do is add a validation cell where it tells the user whether their selected objects will fit in the selected container.

I currently have a formula that does this in a basic way by populating a table from lookup sums, and then doing basic arithmetic in a separate field

Validation table with lookup data:

[image: Validation table with lookup data]

Validation table lookup formulas - note "any shelf" includes leftover from the specific shelf fields:

[image: Validation table lookup formulas - note "any shelf" includes leftover from the specific shelf fields]

I could only include (2) link pics, but there is a cell which returns true if L27, M27 and N27 are all > 0.

The problem with this approach though is that it assumes objects can be "split" amongst multiple shelves.

I am hoping for some help coming up with a formula approach that will perform this validation without allowing "remainders".  This is kind of a "packing" problem, and I am unsure how to approach this in Excel.  I really want to try and do this with a formula and not VBA because I want maximum compatibility and usability.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a rounddown function to get rid of the decimals?

Comment: No, so the issue is, right now the formula looks at what needs to be on specific shelves, and subtracts that from each shelf available length, and then adds the remaining space available on all 3 shelves and compares that to the objects that can be put on any shelf.

Comment: Problem ex: 3.1" left on shelf 1, 1.2" on shelf 2, and 5" on shelf 3. If an object requires 6" on "any", formula sees a total of 9.3" available and says TRUE.

Now, I could add in a check:
`OR([OBJECT LENGTH]<L27,[OBJECT LENGTH]<M27,[OBJECT LENGTH]<N27)`

But that only works if there is one object requiring "any". Trying to figure out a way I can optimize and validate packing on shelves for all objects.

Comment: Can you define your shelves? Is this a warehouse? Does height matter? Does location matter? Do you use forklifts? Does depth matter? For example, I need a shelf 20 inches side, 30 inches deep, 40 inches high. Is this in a small space or large? Front of the house or back? Overstock? Wood? Nails? Desktop supplies? I've worked in warehouseing and inventory control before and so it's curious why such detail is needed on a  workable sheet. But I'm also a computer scientist and math could help too.

Comment: Yeah, no, shelves is a metaphor I thought would be easier to understand.  We're actually talking about DIN rail.  Only one dimension matters.